# Calling a macro from another workbook not always being executed

Tags: vba, excel

In `Excel Workbook A`, I have a `macro` which

1. fills inputs for a series of other workbooks
2. calls the `AUTORUN`
3. collects results in a summary tab

The logic is quite simple but I found that `Step 2` is not always being executed, which is quite strange... I have `confirmed` that inputs have been properly entered and I can go each failed Excel workbook and run the simulation by clicking the button linked to `AUTORUN`. Does anyone have any suggestions on this (I am using EXCEL 2013)? Thanks in advance! Below is how `macro` from a different workbook is called.

```
        Workbooks(NewFileName).Activate
        Application.Run ("'" & NewFileName & "'!AUTORUN")
```

Comment: do you have any error ? Or the code just not run. I should run a test, but if you already set NewFileName as active workbook, you shouldn't need to specify the "NewFileName" in the Application.Run()

Comment: @MaximePorté, no error message or other complain from EXCEL. That is really strange, and I am not sure how to catch this error. Sometimes, the issue goes after after rebooting machine...

Comment: What is the value of "NewFileName" ? And from where do you call this code ? (A sub / function, an event ? which one)
edit: take a look in the "Macro" button (your workbook NewFileName needs to be opened and set yourself on an other workbook), what is the display name of your Autorun function in it ?

Comment: @MaximePorté,  `NewFileName` is the EXCEL file to be called. I call this macro from a `sub`. I have verified that ` "'" & NewFileName & "'!AUTORUN" ` is correct.

Comment: I know NewFileName is the excel file to be called ;) I asked for the value of this variable, I will run some test later in the day if you hadn't find it until then.

Comment: @MaximePorté, sorry my bad, and value of NewFileName is something like `test_6_22_2016.xlsm`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I run some tests

**File 1 (the caller):**

The method AAATEST() is in a Module

```
Public Sub AAATEST()
    Dim file As String: file = "test.xlsm"
    call Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\" & file)

    Workbooks(file).Activate
    Call Application.Run("'" & file & "'!AUTORUN")
End Sub
```

**File 2 (with autorun):**

The method AUTORUN() is in a Module

```
Public Sub AUTORUN()
    MsgBox "autorun is my life"
End Sub
```

**Result:**

I always receive the message when running the AAATEST() method. I suspect a not raised error in the AUTORUN.

To check if the Autorun is run or not, add Stop as first instruction in your Method and execute your code step by step (with F8)

```
Public Sub AUTORUN()
    Stop
    ...
    MsgBox "autorun is my life"
End Sub
```